# How to initialize a typed array in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array called "cart" of objects which looks like this,

`cart:[{name:any, rate:number, qty:number, discount:number, subtotal:number}]`

and I don't want to have any data in it at the beginning, but when I write

`cart:[{name:any, rate:number, qty:number, discount:number, subtotal:number}];`

and try to find the length by using

`Object.keys(this.cart).length`

it shows an error saying

```
`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
```

Also, how to clear all elements in an Array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on my understanding, the following should work for you,

```
interface ISomething {
    name: any;
    rate: number;
    qty: number;
    discount: number;
    subtotal: number
}
let cart: Array<ISomething> = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first initialize the array:

```
cart = [];
```

Also, do this to clear all elements in the array.